# Disable git automerge

Tags: git

Until now, I used to do: 'git pull origin master' and if there was something to merge, I would get an error, then I could use 'git mergetool' (loads p4merge) to merge files.

Now it just writes Fast-forward and auto-merges my files:

```
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Updating 508eb2e..b93d761
Fast-forward
 protected/controllers/AlbumController.php      |   14 +-
 protected/controllers/AlbumController.php.orig |  103 +++
 etc.
```

The thing is, I haven't done anything particular to allow automerging. Why did this happen and how can I disable it?

Comment: In my experience, git has always automerged non-conflicting changes. Is it possible that you've always had conflicts before, and you're not having conflicts now?

Comment: I'm having no conflicts now, but there should be. It basically overwrites all my changes

Comment: I see that you've solved your mystery, but one of the wonderful things about git is that its design makes it REALLY hard to delete things.  For example, had you noticed (or suspected) your teammate's merge was responsible for the deletion of your files, you could have simply pointed your branch to the commit before his to verify the files returned, and then set it back to the tip of the branch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be rather confused. "Fast-forward" means it *didn't* merge. It means that you had no local commits, so it just forwarded your branch pointer to the tip of what you pulled.

Comment: I did a commit a while ago, then I did a pull and there were no conflicts, but the thing is that pull now overwrites basically everything I've changed. It happens the same to my teammates.

Comment: @ifsession: If you did a local commit a while ago, then you pulled and got a merge, any subsequent pull will be a fast-forward. There is no overwriting going on.

Comment: Now I get it, I've made a dumb question :) gratz to my teammate who didn't merge correctly :) and thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

"Fast-forward" means that you haven't made any commits locally that aren't on the remote repository.

This means there is nothing to merge; your local checked out branch has just been brought up to date.

The diff-stat is just there to tell you what changes have been made in the remote since your last pull.

Comment: But why does it then overwrite my files? My 'git status' is empty. My changes were pushed earlier this day, now I'm just trying to pull and merge the changes that my teammates did.

Comment: @ifsession: If your changes have aleady been pushed then they are already on the remote repository. You have nothing to do. If you changes have gone then you need to speak to your teammates as they are the only people who could have merged your changes away.

Comment: Thank you too for your explanation. It helped, but I gave the correct answer mark to the post before yours because it's almost the same.

Answer (score 1):

You have nothing to merge. So it just updates your branch to point to where the one you are merging is pointing to. Your working directory will now be updated to represent the new place that your branch points to. This is what is "overwriting" your files. Why would you expect your working directory's files to not get overwritten after merging in other changes (regardless if it was or wasn't a fast-forward situation).

As a side note, if you DO want to keep your branch point, you can force git to create a new commit even if one was not necessary due to fast-forwarding by adding the `--no-ff` option to your merge command.

I would also recommend reading the progit.org/book about branching and merging. This is behaviour is by design.

Comment: @ifsession, note that some people do even [advocate using `--no-ff` for any merge of a feature branch back to its trunk](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).